# What criteria must a family of sequences meet in order to induce a topology?

Tags: general-topology

What criteria must a family of sequences meet in order to induce a topology?

An obvious condition is that constant sequences should converge, but is there more?

Also, I feel like this is a duplicate, but has been oddly difficult to Google...

Comment: How do sequences yield a topology?

Comment: People sometimes say thugs like “the topology of uniform  or pointwise convergence” implying that there is a background topology when speaking of sequences.

Comment: These are called sequential spaces. Metrizable spaces are an important special case.

Comment: I do know the definition of a sequential space and think it is a different concept. I am wondering when specifying a family of sequences also specifies a topology.

Comment: For instance if the family did not include constant sequences, then it is not the family of convergent sequences of any topology. So there is some nontrivial requirement on such a family.

Comment: A less trivial example is in this paper where convergence in volume is defined using only sequences: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12220-011-9242-8?no-access=true

Comment: Oh, you want criteria on the set of sequences rather than the space. Yeah that is a bit nonstandard...

Comment: That’s right. I have seen it treated once before and there is a fairly simple criterion but I am unable to find it. The question is mostly useful when you have a notion of convergence that would be convenient for a particular application and you want to make sure it has a supporting topology.

Comment: This is related: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subsequential+space

Comment: Indeed. The answer is probably on that site if one can parse it and follow the appropriate links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Engelking *General Topology* ex 1.7.18/19, that follow papers by Fréchet and Urysohn and Kisyński, look up the references there.)
Let $X^\mathbb{N}$ be the set of all sequences on $X$.

Suppose we have a function from $\lambda: \mathscr{C} \subseteq X^\mathbb{N} \to X$, where $\mathscr{C}$ is a designated set of "convergent sequences", and $\lambda((x_n)_n) = x$ says that $x$ is the limit of the sequence, also denoted $x_n \to x \,(n \to \infty)$.

Then $(X,\lambda)$ is called a $\mathscr{L}^\ast$-space when it satisfies the following three axioms:

> **L1** If $x_n = x$ for all $n$, then $x_n \to x$. (constant sequences converge to their constant.)
>
> **L2** If $x_n \to x$ then $x_{n_k} \to x \,(k \to \infty)$ for every subsequence of $x_n$ (or $\lambda((x_{n_k})_k) = x$)
>
> **L3** If a sequence $(x_n)_n$ does *not* converge  to $x$, then there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ of $(x_n)_n$ such that *no* subsequence of $(x_{n_k})_k$ converges to $x$.
>
> An alternative logical formulation of **L3** is: if every subsequence of a sequence has a sub-subsequence that converges to $x$, then the original sequence converges to $x$.

Then we can define a so-called [closure operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms) on $X$ by:

> $x \in \overline{A}$ iff $\exists (x_n)_n \in \mathscr{C} \cap A^\mathbb{N}: \lambda((x_n)_n)  =x$

so $x$ is in the closure of $A$ iff there is a sequence from $A$ converging to $x$.

This satisfies the first 3 axioms of a closure operator but not idempotence $\overline{\overline{A}} = \overline{A}$, we only have a [preclosure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preclosure_operator) which does define a (the so-called Fréchet) topology (via "$A$ is closed" iff $A = \overline{A}$), but such that the closure-operator in this induced topology is not always equal to the orginal closure operation from the convergence, which is maybe not what you'd like.

In order to get that extra condition we need we define another axiom

**L4** If $x_n \to x (n \to \infty)$ and for every $n$, $x^n_k \to x_n (k \to \infty)$ then there exist integer sequences $n_1, n_2, \ldots$ ,$k_1, k_2, \ldots$ such that $x^{n_l}_{k_l} \to x \,(l \to \infty)$

And we can show that $\overline{A}$ defined above from the convergence is idempotent iff it **also** satisfies **L4**.  A space satisfying **L1**-**L4** is called an $\mathscr{S}^\ast$ space, and in those the sequential closure equals its topological closure and moreover the topological convergence is the same as the formal convergence relation $\lambda$ we started with.

Kisyński (1960) then showed that in an $\mathscr{L}^\ast$ space we can also define a topology directly, without a preclosure operation:

> $C \subseteq X$ is closed if for every sequence from $C$ that converges, its limit lies in $C$ as well.

This is the *sequential topology* induced by $\lambda$ (as opposed to the *Fréchet topology* induced by the preclosure) and it can be shown that an $\mathscr{L}^\ast$ topology is $T_1$ in this sequential topology. In an $\mathscr{S}^\ast$ space the Fréchet topology and the sequential topology coincide.

Exercise 1.7.20 then goes on to connect these ideas to the notions of a sequential and a Fréchet topological space. I warmly commend this great resource to your attention. You could go back to the original papers if you read French.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking of. Thank you!

Comment: @ZachBoyd Glad to be of help. Good holidays!